# How to check if the OS is a Debian derivative (Python)

Tags: python, operating-system, debian

What is a good way to determine whether the OS is Debian derivative (and also in the future I will need the same functionality for Fedora, FreeBSD, etc.) from a Python script?

I need this to choose whether I use `dpkg -s` command to determine which software is installed or I fall back to checking if there is a command in `PATH`.

For example to determine whether `xsltproc` package is installed (and its version, if possible), I use `dpkg -s xsltproc` if it is a Debian or derivative system or check whether there is `xsltproc` in the `PATH` otherwise.

Comment: One day, all distros will use [FlatPack](https://flatpak.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Some people might encourage you to look for the feature that you want to use rather than the distro and then inferring what you should use based on that.  For example, if you want to use `dpkg`, check that it exists and then use it if you can.

However, that doesn't answer your specific question...  How can you actually tell what distribution you are running on?  There are a couple of options depending on what version of Python you're running:

1. Use `platform.linux_distribution()`.  As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution), it will return a tuple of `(distro name, version, id)`.  However, it has been deprecated in Python 3 and will be removed by 3.8.
2. Use the `distro` package.  As documented [here](https://github.com/nir0s/distro) you get something remarkably similar by installing this package and then calling `distro.linux_distribution()`.  Release notes say that this will work on 2.7 and 3.4+.

There are older options than that, but they have been deprecated since 2.6 so I've not included them here.